# Gradle does not recognize the JAVA_HOME I have set

Tags: bash, gradle, jvm, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

I have set my `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`, which contains a valid JVM, but gradle insists on using `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` and complains about `JAVA_HOME`:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
$ ls $JAVA_HOME
bin  COPYRIGHT  db  include  jre  lib  LICENSE  man  README.html  release  src.zip  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
$ gradle assemble

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

How can I fix this and have gradle use my valid `JAVA_HOME`?

*Note: My `JAVA_HOME` is set by `~/.bashrc` using `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"`*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

it is quite common issue. Just go to your gradle home directory and `bin`, for example:

```
/home/user/gradle-2.0/bin
```

and there you should have gradle script, I am on a Windows machine now so I have `gradle.bat`, probably you will have `gradle.sh` or something like this. In that file, find the line:

```
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
```

or as I can see you are on linux so there will be "export" and change it to your java home directory for example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Comment: Indeed! Line 70 of `/usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle` is `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`. Removing that line fixes the problem.

Comment: This happens in newer versions also. where the 70th line mentioned here is removed in gradle script. This is how I fixed it,

run `which java` and take it's result. remove the `/bin/java` from that and use it to set the `JAVA_HOME`. Then call the `gradlew` command.

Answer (score 1):

If on windows, also make changes to JAVA_EXE and add your path

```
    set JAVA_EXE=C:\yourpath\bin\java.exe
```