# Running gradle -v returns "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory" even though I have a valid JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to install and use gradle 2.7

I have java installed properly:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

I have my JAVA_HOME set correctly:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I run gradle -v:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I tried to use the solution given here [Gradle does not recognize the JAVA_HOME I have set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882221/gradle-does-not-recognize-the-java-home-i-have-set) and here [Gradle finds wrong JAVA_HOME even though it's correctly set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set)

but that line does not exist in my gradle file located at `/usr/local/gradle/gradle-2.7/bin`

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Edit:
cat ~/.bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export JDK_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=/Users/eghdk/Dev/Android/SDK/platform-tools:/Users/eghdk/Dev/Android/SDK/tools:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/eghdk/Dev/Android/SDK
# Adding Gradle to system path
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/gradle/gradle-2.7
PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
# Turning on the Gradle daemon by default
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
```

Comment: could you try to run this command `export | grep JAVA` in terminal?

Comment: does the directory /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home have a `bin` subdirectory with `java` in it?

Comment: @kucing_terbang output: `declare -x JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents"Home`

Comment: @Henry yes, `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin` has java and other java* files in it.

Comment: @EGHDK Ok, then, is the command (`declare -x`) is put into something like `.profile` or `.bash_profile` file?

Comment: I ran `cat ~/.bash_profile` and put the output into an edit of the question @kucing_terbang

Comment: Is your previous output a typo, e.g., that quote between `Contents` and `Home`? What version of OS X? I'm running Java build 1.8.0_45-b14 and Gradle 2.7 and I can't reproduce this, but I also installed Gradle in my user directory because when it comes to Java libraries I never do any automatic installation (e.g., no homebrew of Java artifacts).

Comment: @DaveNewton not a typo. That's the exact copy and paste of the output. I'm guessing the `"` shouldn't be there?

Comment: Not unless you have a particularly funky Java install ;) It's disturbing that the echo and gradle have the correct `/`, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton do you have any idea of what to do to fix that?