# Java home supplied via 'org.gradle.java.home' is invalid. Invalid directory: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05

Tags: gradle

I'm using gradle 2.9, intellij and Win10 for spring development. In one particular project I encountered this error:

```
Java home supplied via 'org.gradle.java.home' is invalid. Invalid directory: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05
```

Neither
[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set)  nor [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882221/gradle-does-not-recognize-the-java-home-i-have-set) work for me.

Comment: the path seems like Unix path to me, not windows path

Answer (score 86):

Finally I found my solution. In the project root I found `gradle.properties` configure this java home

```
 org.gradle.java.home=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05
```

I remove and build it properly.

Comment: after 30 tries, I finally find this. It solves the problem

Comment: There are two `gradle.properties` files being checked: the one in the project, and the one in the `~/.gradle` directory.

Comment: For me on Linux (Fedora), a working Java path ended up being `org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk/`

This is after installing OpenJDK with `sudo dnf install java-latest-openjdk.x86_64`

Answer (score 38):

1. Check the global gradle configuration in `C:\Users\<user>\.gradle`
2. In your android project you will have a file named `gradle.properties`
3. Delete `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144`

Comment: the OP has found the solution long back and added a similar answer already

Comment: The accepted answer explicitely asks to look for the properties file in the project root directory. However there are global and local gradle properties and either can be responsible for setting this property value. This one refers to global settings and is in my opinion not the same solution, even though it targets the same attribute. +1

Comment: Helped when adding to `~/.zshrc` instead.

Answer (score 21):

1. In your android project you will have a file name gradle.properties.
2. Open up that file, there will a line

> org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144

3. You will have to change this line, insert your jdk setup
   location, most important use double backslashes "\\" like above in your path.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone on MacBooks, you might want to check if the file in `/Users/username/.gradle/gradle.properties` has the correct JDK path provided.

I was receiving the following message in Android Studio:

> Value '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)

My `gradle.properties` file had the following line:

> org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

And I had to change it to the following:

> org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio 4.1.3.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
> Since I renamed `Android Studio.app` to `Android Studio 4.1.3.app` since I have multiple installations.

Answer (score 3):

After updating to android studio giraffe I changed `jre` to `jbr` on M1 mac

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/

org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you use visual studio code open folder `android\gradle.properties`.
2. Change the path `org.gradle.java.home = <local path>\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I removed this line from my `android/gradle.properties`:

> org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

And then I edited my `android/local.properties` and gave the right sdk directory path which can be found in `android studio -> preferences -> Appearance & behaviour -> System settings -> Android sdk`

Apparently I moved my code from one machine to another so the sdk path was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
```

---

from gradle.properties. This will work for you.

Comment: worked for me on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

1. If you use visual studio code open the folder android\gradle.properties.
2. Delete This line `org.gradle.java.home= C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_361`

[check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3qRw.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Mac M1 chip users, add the following line in **gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home //////-ADD THIS LINE ONLY
```

you can find your java home path

> AndroidStudio -> File -> ProjectStructure -> SDKs -> Android studio
> java home

[image: Java Home Path]

Answer (score 0):

Open `android/gradle.properties` and check `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` this line available or not. If available, then comment out/remove this line and try to run.

This works for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the 'Android' folder.
2. Find & open the file named 'gradle.properties'.
3. Remove the following line (anyone you find)

   - org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
   - org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
4. Save the file and run the command 'npx react-native run-android'.
   That's it!