# Program trying to build with uninstalled version of JDK

Tags: java

Using the Oracle installer, I installed jdk-21 on my windows computer. However, when I tried to build a project, an error message suggested that gradlew was incompatible, so I uninstalled the Oracle jdk-21, and now I've installed the Adoptium build and I set JAVA_HOME using this command

`setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot"`

When I run where java in the command prompt, I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk.21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin\java.exe
```

However, when I try to build my project, I get an error message that it can't find the java excutable "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe". It seems that my computer is trying to find the oracle version I uninstalled.

I set `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in the system path as instructed in this  [article](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-windows-10) and it says it can't find the executable.

This is the first entry in my path in environment variables

```
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin
```

This is my last entry

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Why is the program looking to build with an uninstalled version (i.e. the Oracle version that I removed) of Java?

[This link](https://imgur.com/a/YvuDvgp) shows screenshots of my java path on my windows computer.

[This Java Spring project](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-opentelemetry-examples) is what I'm trying to build.

Comment: The error probably means that your Gradle version cannot use Java 21, so installing another Java 21 of a different vendor is not going to help. Use an earlier supported version (e.g. Java 17). That said, the error indicates that your PATH or JAVA_HOME is still not set correctly. Likely you still have Oracle's `javapath` directory (or whatever it is called) on the `PATH`. You need to remove it from the list of path entries.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel.  I neglected to mention in the OP that Oracle's javapath had been removed from the PATH before I wrote this question, so that's not the problem afaict

Comment: Type `which java` in cmd.exe and you'll see where it finds the executable. Type `echo %PATH%` to see the current PATH. You may need to reboot or log out and back in, in order to refresh the path.

Comment: there is no which command on windows. However, I think these screenshots of both command line path and Windows environment variables show everything you need.  Thank you for looking. 
 https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/y3uivthiaok8liae3l5lb/h?rlkey=9rk4skib8sjxg6ajbet3ji577&dl=0

Comment: @Leahcim You can use `where java` in Windows CMD.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant `where` instead of `which`. Too much recent use of Linux.

Comment: You might find a version of `java.exe` in C:\Windows\System32. Some early versions of Oracle's Java installers used to copy that file into there. That's why `where java` is important, even if your PATH is known.

Comment: `where java` produces no output on `powershell` but on the regular windows command prompt it shows the Eclipse Adoptium version: `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk.21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin\java.exe`

Comment: Check if your build script contains the hard-coded location "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21". Also, make sure you're using the latest version of Gradle (anything less than v 8.5 doesn't work with Java 21).

Comment: There's no hard coded reference to location. The java program I'm trying to build is a tutorial. You can see the repo here. It looks to see if java home is set, which mine is. https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-opentelemetry-examples.git

Comment: I also updated gradle to 8.5 and the result is the same

Comment: What output do you get with `where gradle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this has something to with gradle cache mecanism. Delete the `.gradle/daemon/<version>/registry.bin` file and it should use your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Here is the [gradle daemon documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html). Maybe this [part](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#memory_caching) causes the follow up error you described in the comments. You can disable the daemon for the current build with `gradle <task> --no-daemon` and check if your project will build.

Comment: I deleted file, ran `gradlew.bat build`: This is  error message. Does it mean you solved the problem &  I've run into new different problem or if the error message doesn't rule out that my original problem still exists. please explain: ` * What went wrong:
Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\michaelm\new_relic\getting-started-guides\java\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Malle\.gradle\caches\8.0.1\scripts\5aci2ld0xckmx8f04e3sp09ir).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65`

Comment: You can delete everything in `daemon` folder. `gradle` will recreate it. Maybe this solve it. On the over hand `unsupported class file.... ` is a typical error when the JVM doesn't support the JDK you compiled the class files with.

Comment: You should also clear the `. gradle\caches` folder.

Answer (score 2):

The project you linked to is using Gradle 8.0.1.
Running that with Java 21 is not supported as you can see at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html.
So to build that project unchanged, you have to run Gradle with at most Java 19.

That the old Java installation is used even though `JAVA_HOME` is set to the new location sounds strange, **if** you actually run Gradle from commandline. If you run it from IDE, you have to check the IDE settings.

Right now I could only imagine that in your `GRADLE_USER_HOME` (typically `.gradle/` in your user home) you have a `gradle.properties` where you set the path to that old Java installation.

If that is not the case, the question is, what is the exact output of you trying to run the build, respectively where is the error coming from exactly. If it is from the Gradle wrapper script, you could switch off the echo-suppression to see what is actually happening for example.

Comment: I have cloned another java project to my computer and I'm able to build and run it by doing `javac` and `java` etc. This is the project.:  https://github.com/SidharthMudgil/mini-projects/blob/main/java/digital-clock/out/production/digital%20clock/Frame.class  so it seems my problem that prompted the OP is only specific to that one project or gradle related. Does that help you provide a definitive answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as you do not have problems with `java` or `javac` in your `PATH`, but with running Gradle. All I can deduct from the given information is already mentioned in my answer. Did you check where I pointed you to? And if so, you still did not provide the  output I mentioned.

Comment: I just figured out where `./gradle` is. I don't see a `gradles.properties` though. Can you suggest where I might look. In the gradle dir, there is `.tmp` `caches` `daemon` `native` `notifications` `wrapper`. when I run `gradle -version` in the command prompt, it says `8.5` but in `.gradle\wrapper\dists` it lists `gradle-8.0.1.bin`

Comment: It would be directly in that directory if it were there, so if it is not there, it is not the case. In `wrapper/dists` you have the distributions that are downloaded and used by the Gradle wrapper that you should always use to build a project. `gradle --version` shows the version of your installed Gradle version which is irrelevant in 99% of the cases. Usually, you should not even have any Gradle version installed at all.

Comment: Sure it does. There after `runtime`. But this is pretty irrelevant, you do not have a problem with Maven. You still did not follow my last paragraph. Why are you avoiding so hard to get help?

Comment: The exact output of running the build is: `FAILURE: build failed with an exception. The supplied javaHome appears to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried locaton : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe`

Comment: Is that really the "exact" output?

Comment: The 'FAILURE' looks like a message from IntelliJ Gradle Plugin.

Comment: Can you execute the command `set` in the terminal where you use gradle? So we can see all environment vars.

Comment: @Easterwood it does not look like being from IJ Gradle plugin, especially when he executes the build from commandline. It vaguely looks like a message that could come from Gradle, but only if "exact" was not correct.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Windows in a while, but IIRC, the Oracle Java installation on Windows left files in key places that made it difficult to reason about which version of Java is being used. To make things worse, these files are not removed on uninstallation.

See if the Oracle installer had left behind:

- c:\windows\system32\java.exe
- c:\windows\system32\javaw.exe

As I believe these often take precedence on the `PATH`.

Comment: There is a `javaws` file under `c:\windows.system\32` but not the files you specified

Answer (score 1):

Try running this on the command line:

```
gradlew --debug clean > out.tmp
```

Then open `out.tmp` (it's a very large file) in a text editor and search for Java (case-insensitive). At some point, you might find the reason it's picking the wrong version.

Comment: when I ran that command, I got this output. `FAILURE: build failed with an exception. The supplied javaHome appears to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried locaton : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe`

Comment: but `where java` outputs `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin\java.exe`

Comment: `where java` and the `java` or `javac` comments are unrelated to JAVA_HOME. The latter is only used by tools like Gradle, not by Java itself. If Gradle is saying "javaHome appears to be invalid", type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` immediately after running Gradle, in the same cmd window. Besides the JAVA_HOME environment variable, there are other ways that this can get misconfigured: for example, check any command lines the the build file for options like `-D java.home=...`

Comment: I've tried to clone and build and run one other project that doesn't use gradle and there's no problem. Interestingly, I also tried your suggestion about doing `echo %JAVA_HOME% after running gradle. The echo command says, `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot`, whereas gradle is looking for it in a different location

Comment: I installed apache maven and was able to build another java project with it. However, the documentation for maven said that mvn -v should output the Java Home, and it didn't in my case. It said this mvn -v Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae) Maven home: C:\michaelm\apache-maven-3.9.6 Java version: 21.0.1, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: The "runtime" output by `mvn` is the same thing as java home.

Comment: Have you checked `GRADLE_HOME` as per [Vampire's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77852984/638028)? Have you looked at previous questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356796/intellij-gradle-plugin-the-supplied-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid) (even though it relates to use of IntelliJ IDEA) or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010338/java-home-supplied-via-org-gradle-java-home-is-invalid-invalid-directory-us)?